# Make font sharper in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to make the font sharper in PhpStorm?

Solutions online suggest going to "Compatibility" and choosing "Disable DPI scaling on high DPI settings". I don't see that option in my version (2019.3)

It's not a huge difference but it's definitely noticeable after a while. I changed font to Menlo (same as in Sublime, but it didn't help)

Attaching a screenshot of how PhpsSorm shows text (on the left) vs Sublime Text editor (on the right):
[image]

Comment: macOS I assume (Mac users are the ones that see such difference the most)? Anyway, in general, check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/JBR?q=font for a font rendering tickets.

Comment: @LazyOne hi, yep macOS indeed. Okey thank you, I also opened a ticket, hopefully can find a solution and post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per support should use "greyscale" instead "subpixel" (see the screenshot below). This fixed the issue for me. Super sharp now.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it helps with the red/blue aspect, at least.
But isn't calling this "Super sharp" a bit exaggerated ?  It's actually still blurry everywhere, just without random colors on the left/right :(